# Using PuPHPet to configure Vagrant, but need more advanced options

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, puphpet

I'm currently using the PuPHPet Vagrant config page. Once completed I then have to manually set a few other things up. This isn't ideal, and ideally PuPHPet will do it all in one go.

(1) I don't see the Apache mod_expires available in the options. I want to set this on puphpet.com somehow.

(2) I also currently have to edit this line in my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "#{folder['source']}", "#{folder['target']}", id: "#{folder['id']}", type: nfs
```

...and add this to the end:

```
, mount_options: ["dmode=777,fmode=777"]
```

It prevents Vagrant complaining of file permission problems in Symfony2.

I want Puphpet.com to handle that automatically too.

Is this possible?

I notice on https://puphpet.com/help that the section which mentions "Simply look inside your downloaded folder and open puppet/hieradata/common.yaml" may have something to do with it, but the folder I get after completing a config on puphpet.com doesn't have a common.yaml file in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation is somewhat out of date, that file is now called config.yaml.

How to further configure it, say to tweak Apache settings (e.g. EnableSendfile Off), could use further elaboration on the tool's website. The project's lead commented on SO a couple months ago that updating the documentation was on his to-do list.